# How to open a file in Lisp and specify both ':if-exists :append' and also ':if-does-not-exist :create'

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to make some Lisp code which gracefully handles files that both do exist or don't exist.

So sometimes I start with a file that already exists and has text like "This is original text not lisp text"

```
(defparameter s (open "s.txt"
                          :direction :io
                          :if-does-not-exist :create
                          :if-exists :append))
=>s
(print "first line" s)
=>"first line"
(print "second Line" s)
=>"second line"
(read s)
=>ERRORs End of file reached. "; Evaluation aborted on #<END-OF-FILE {10045973C3}>."
Over to a cmd window:
$cat s.txt 
This is original text not lisp text.
```

That is the full interaction. Further more however the text already in s.txt is completely unchanged.

This however simply fails to actually append or overwrite text to the file at all.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the commands used, what is the actual result, and what was produced instead (“simply fails to actually append to the file" is not very informative).

Comment: Are you using `file-position` to jump to the end of the file before writing? By default, when you open with `:direction :io`, it opens to the beginning of the file, and you end up overwriting whatever was there last time the file was written.

Comment: Since you have written nothing to the file, nothing can't be appended.

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial, for working with files, your code works, but the problem is you do not know what it does http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. 
I was keeping the file open in a text editor (notepad.exe) and then re-opening it to see if it had been updated. 
I guess first of all

```
(close s)
```

is what actually causes the writes out to disk. Nothing else will show up in another text editor until close is called.

Comment: It is in most cases better to use `with-open-file` which establishes a scope which unwind-protects in order to always close the file when leaving.

Comment: @Svante : Everybody says this and yet it doesn't allow interactive use when prototyping so I find myself putting it in at the end and not actually using it when I'm developing.

Comment: Maybe we are working on different things, but I have yet to find a situation where I feel the need to keep a file open while poking at things.

Comment: @Svante I know this is literally years later, but at the time I was preoccupied with collaborative editing. Like google docs where multiple people have cursors in the same data buffer. I haven't made much progress since but I hope that gives you some of my ambitious and naive thought space.

Comment: Interesting.  But that kind of collaboration leads to very different considerations and designs.  In that case, you won't open or close files in this sense.  Instead you will have to think in terms of several locations of the same file, which are synchronized to eventual consistency using CRDTs.  For further reading e. g. look at https://www.inkandswitch.com/local-first/

Comment: That is a very cool link thank you! Also, after learning some lisp file operations and getting frustrated with a lack of understanding of what was being abstracted I got completely thrown off lisp and into lower level programming where the inherent nature of the shared memory+cpu access etc becomes more clear. That process happened pretty much because of this question. That's why 7 years later things are clearer. Confusion about what exactly has and hasn't been abstracted is on display here.

Answer (score 1):

As [Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69545/rainer-joswig) pointed out, you are opening a file but not writing anything in your piece of code. Moreover, if you just want to append, open the file with output direction. A simple function to open a file and append something to it would be like this:

```
    (defun write-smth-to-file (file-out smth)
      (with-open-file (f file-out :direction :output 
                                  :if-exists :append 
                                  :if-does-not-exist :create)
        "Function to open a file and append something to it"
        (format f "~a~%" smth)))
```

Comment: You have one extra ending paren :)

Comment: I wrote the answer with the cell phone ;)